# creating records of self referring model causing error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have self referring model defined as :

```
        App.Answer = DS.Model.extend({
            name: DS.attr('string'),
            parentAnswer: DS.belongsTo('answer'),
            childAnswers: DS.hasMany('answer')
        });
```

I am not sure how to define the inverse property to get things working. Here is a jsbin of what I have : http://jsbin.com/oKezUkaz/1/

If we add a group(pressing "Add group" button) we get error in the console saying:

```
Assertion failed: You defined the 'childAnswers' relationship on App.Answer, but multiple possible inverse relationships of type App.Answer were found on App.Answer. Look at http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_explicit-inverses for how to explicitly specify inverses
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to define `inverse` on both, or it gets stuck in a loop going down one of the path's.  Ember Data's documentation is lacking on this, but should be worked on after ED gets to a solid 1.0.

```
App.Answer = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  parentAnswer: DS.belongsTo('answer', {inverse: 'childAnswers'}),
  childAnswers: DS.hasMany('answer', {inverse: 'parentAnswer'})
});
```

http://jsbin.com/oKezUkaz/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

Your model must be defined like this

```
 App.Parent = DS.Model.extend({
        answer: DS.belongsTo('parant')
      });
      App.Child = DS.Model.extend({
        answer: DS.hasMany('child')
      });

        App.Answer = DS.Model.extend({
            name: DS.attr('string'),
          parent: DS.belongsTo('answer'),
            child: DS.belongsTo('answer')
        });
```

I can't understand what you wanna to achive but i this this is the proper way.

Comment: See in my case, an answer can have many child answers. I need to be able to add child answer at any level of hierarchy so I have parent answer in my model too because it makes adding sibling answers in same level super easy.

Comment: In this case chlid must be hasMany too.